# "It was not possible to retrieve ruleset information" when executing Business rules on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

When executing my rules deployed on the Business rules service on Bluemix, I see the following exception:

> ilog.rules.res.session.IlrSessionCreationException: An error occurred
>   while the rule session was created:
>   com.ibm.rules.res.xu.internal.XUException: It was not possible to
>   retrieve ruleset information: /MyRuleApp.
>   ilog.rules.res.persistence.IlrDAOException: Wrong path
>   used:"/MyRuleApp".
>   ilog.rules.res.session.IlrJ2SESessionFactory.createStatefulSession(IlrJ2SESessionFactory.java:125)
>   ilog.rules.res.session.impl.IlrSessionFactoryBase.createStatefulSession(IlrSessionFactoryBase.java:158)
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.DecisionServiceController.getStatefulSessionBase(DecisionServiceController.java:163)
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.onMessage(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:836)
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.handleRequest(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:750)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had specified an incomplete URL for the REST POST request for the rule service, which did not specify the path to the ruleset:

```
https://brsv2-12345678.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest/MyRuleApp
```

Once I updated the URL to point to the RuleApp version and ruleset version, the POST request executed successfully:

```
https://brsv2-12345678.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest/MyRuleApp/1.0/myrules/1.0
```

Comment: The URL is found in the Details page of the ruleset found in the Business Rules service instance.